# How to position a user control in the canvas?

Tags: silverlight

I have certain rectangular usercontrols. How can I place it at a certain x-y coordinate in the canvas? Once I place a user control, I need to evaluate the position to place the next control based on the rendered width/height of the previously placed control. How to do these correctly in Silverlight.

Comment: Can you give us example of what you did and what didn't work? It will help us help you..

Comment: I have been using margin property to position the controls. I don't know how to place a control w.r.t the position and rendered size of an already placed control.

Comment: Example would be great but aligning controls inside others can be easily done with HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment

Answer (score 2):

To position controls inside a canvas panel, you use the Canvas class's attached properties, Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. So, if you wanted your control to be positioned at 100,20 (relative to the top-left corner of the canvas), you would enter:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="20"/>
</Canvas>
```

Alternatively, you could use this in the code-behind:

```
yourControl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,100.0);
yourControl.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty,20.0);
```

If you've got several controls you're trying to arrange dynamically though, you may want to consider using a StackPanel or Grid intead of a Canvas.

Comment: If the layout logic is reusable, you might consider creating a custom panel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903936%28v=vs.95%29.aspx